# Will changing subscription interrupt bulk insert with an Azure SQL database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

Long story short, my database crashed and I wish to restore it. I am moving everything to Azure. I have a free trial subscription and have been running a bcp bulk insert for the past 4 hours.

I need more power, so I would like to move the SQL database to a new subscription and its forcing me to move the resource group as well. Will this interrupt my bcp bulk insert?

Answer (score 0):

I had to take the chance. It did not interrupt.Boy what a difference when I increased DTU from 50 to 400.

Comment: For IO intensive workloads, premium tiers are recommended. Scale up before the bulk insert and when finish scale down to original tier.